# Calling Constructor with parameters resets previously initialized data elements - release/debug VS17

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working with classes (C++) for pretty much the first time with the intend of doing something useful. And that's where I encountered the first problem :D
I learned that the Constructor without parameters get's called right after the object is defined. Which it actually does.
But for some reason Visual Studio 2017 has some strange behaviour when it gets to the release/debug setting. When set to "Debug", calling a constructor with parameters, after the one without, the previously defined "test" data element returns to being uninitialized.
When in "Release" mode the "test" data element stays initialized to the value 44 (if the destructor is empty, otherwise it shows test = 0).

Is this somehow expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance! :)

This example should trigger the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor()\n";
        test = 44;
    }

    Class(int parameter)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor(param): " << parameter;
    }

    ~Class() { std::cout << "Destructor"; }

    void get(void)
    {
        std::cout << "test = " << test << '\n';
    }

protected:
    int test;
};

int main()
{
    Class Ins;       // constructor without parameters gets called
    Ins.get();       // outputs 44
    Ins = Class(55); // constructor with parameters gets called

    Ins.get();       // *PROBLEM* should show 44 at all time?

    /*
    DEBUG-MODE -> test = (undefined rubbish)

                  _ empty destructor:            test = 44;
                 /
    RELEASE MODE-
                 \_ destructor with cout output:  test = 0;
    */
}
```

#### Output:

```
Constructor()
test = 44
Constructor(param): 55
Destructor
test = -858993460  /* <- for debug build */
test = 44 /* <- for release build (empty destructor) */
test = 0 /* <- for release build (cout inside destructor) */

Destructor
```

But I expected `test = 44` in all cases.

Comment: The comments aren't really clear, to me at least. What is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: @JLIspace: Sorry for taking your code apart (or rather: merging it). But for asking questions that are not about scenarios where it matters that code is in different files, it is more appropriate to present one file that contains everything neccessary to reproduce the reason for the question. Also have a look at [mcve].

Comment: @Swordfish That's totally fine! It's definitely clearer now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor with parameter:

```
Class::Class(int parameter)
{
    cout << "Constructor(param)" << parameter;
}
```

does not actually set `test`. Therefore `test` will be uninitialized (technically default-initialized) and have an unspecified value after the `Class` object has been constructed.

In `Ins = Class(55);` you are creating such an instance with `Class(55)` and then assign it to the other instance `Ins`. Absent some exceptions, the compiler will generate an assignment operator automatically, which will simply copy the variable `test` from the right-hand instance to the left-hand one. Therefore after `Ins = Class(55);` the instance `Ins` will have the unspecified value in `test`.

Because the value of the variable will be unspecified, the compiler may choose to use anything there and is also perfectly allowed to give different values depending on compiler options, such as Debug/Release Mode, or even just in different program invocations.

Always set all members in constructors, preferably via member initialization list like so:

```
Class::Class(int parameter)
    : test(parameter)
{
    cout << "Constructor(param)" << parameter;
}

Class::Class()
    : test(0)
{
    std::cout << "Constructor()\n";
}
```

Comment: `gcc` 8.2 and `clang` 7 (both `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and `cl` 19.16.26926 (`/W4`) won't warn. And technically speaking they are all right because `Class::test` is initialized. *default-initialized*.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. So basically the test variable actually still showing 44 in release build is pure kindness from the compiler?

Comment: @JLIspace: for an `int`, default-initialization means that nothing is done. If a variable by accident occupies the same space of another variable previously occupying that space, it is totally possible that it "inherits" its value. But that is nothing that is guaranteed.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes you are right, although gcc 8.2 does warn for `Class Ins(44); Ins.get()`.

Comment: @Swordfish https://godbolt.org/z/z6yydE Apparently only if optimizations are enabled and if the second `get` is dropped.